# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate set params with OR operator and check for null

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, named-parameters

```
class Request{
    private string f1;
    private string f2;
    private string f3;
}
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE f1  = 'val' OR f2  = 'val2' OR f3  = 'va3'
```

fields from `Request` can be `null`. I need to create `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` query and check each field for `null`.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl"; 
if (request.getF1() !=null && !request.getF1().isEmpty()){
            query += ....
        }
```

This is a very bad solution....

Can I create something like

```
 Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<>();
```

to check all fields for `null` and if not `null` add to map and set to query? And set operator `OR`

Answer (score 0):

in jdbc-template you can't do dynamically-query builder out of box (if value is null exclude it from where section). You should create your own builder.

if you need to ececute dynamic query in one- two places you can do that :

just to refactor `request.getF1() !=null && !request.getF1().isEmpty()` into something readable and supportable , something like :

```
String select = SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper.getInstance().
                applyIfPresentValue(fieldName1 , value1).
                applyIfPresentValue("" , null).
                applyIfPresentValue(fieldName2 , value2)
                .buildSqlWithWhere(GIVEN_SELECT);



public final class SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper {
    private StringBuffer whereSqlQuery = new StringBuffer();
    public static final String WHERE = " where ";
    public static final String OR = " or ";
    private boolean whereNotPresent = true;

    private SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper() {
    }

    public static SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper getInstance() {
        return new SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper();
    }

    public SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper applyIfPresentValue(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
        if (isNotEmpty(fieldValue) && isNotEmpty(fieldName)) {
            applyWhereOrOr(fieldName + "=" + wrapValue(fieldValue));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String buildSqlWithWhere(String mainQueryWithoutWhere) {
        return mainQueryWithoutWhere + whereSqlQuery.toString();
    }

    //private section
    private String wrapValue(String fieldValue) {
        return "'" + fieldValue + "'";
    }

    private void applyWhereOrOr(String predicate) {
        String prefix = OR;
        if (whereNotPresent) {
            whereNotPresent = false;
            prefix = WHERE;
        }
        whereSqlQuery.append(prefix);
        whereSqlQuery.append(predicate);
    }

    //if you have apache common(or some other implementation) use  method from lib StringUtils.isEmpty(String value)
    private boolean isNotEmpty(String value) {
        return value != null && value.trim().length() > 0;
    }

}
```

and test for it

```
 private static final String GIVEN_SELECT = "select * from table";

 @Test
    public void testForWithParamsWithNull(){
        //set-up data
        String fieldName1 = "field1";
        String value1 = "value for field1";

        String fieldName2 = "field2";
        String value2 = "value for field2";

        StringBuffer expectedSelectBuffer = new StringBuffer(GIVEN_SELECT);
        expectedSelectBuffer.append(SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper.WHERE);
        expectedSelectBuffer.append(fieldName1+"='"+value1+"'");
        expectedSelectBuffer.append(SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper.OR);
        expectedSelectBuffer.append(fieldName2+"='"+value2+"'");
        String expectedSelect = expectedSelectBuffer.toString();

        //execution

        String resultSelect = SqlDynamicWhereSectionWithOrHelper.getInstance().
                applyIfPresentValue(fieldName1 , value1).
                applyIfPresentValue("" , null).
                applyIfPresentValue(fieldName2 , value2)
                .buildSqlWithWhere(GIVEN_SELECT);

        //verification
        assertThat(resultSelect , is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(resultSelect ,equalTo(expectedSelect));
    }
```

---

Also you can try to fix it in SQL with checking on empty, but if you have lots of data to go through, this technique will slow down your request.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (f1  = 'val' or f1 = null) OR (f2  = 'val2' or f2 = null ) OR (f3  = 'va3' or f3=null)
```